# C++ - Is std::string suitable for storing a large text file, and if not what is the best data type for doing so?

Tags: c++

I was just wondering, what is the best data type for storing the contents of a text-based file?  Is std::string suitable for keeping the contents of a larger file in memory?

I'm making an editor of sorts right now so I'd like to know, I can't seem to find a good answer.

Edit:  Yeah, this was a very vague question and I didn't expect it to get quite as much attention.  Saying it's an editor is kinda a bad description, and the question is quite vague, I was just wondering how to store read-only text in memory, if `std::string`is a bad way to do so; if it is inefficient or not.

Comment: Text files are usually line based, so a `std::vector<std::string>` may be more appropriate and easier to work with for loading into memory.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. For an editor, probably not. You want a data-structure optimised for inserting/deleting/finding lines. Maybe you even need ancilliary data for syntax highlighting and the like...

Comment: @crashmstr: that does risk non-locality of data in memory, though.

Comment: You might be looking for a rope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(computer_science).

Comment: For what it's worth most text editors store their contents in memory,  you'll notice this limitation if you ever try to load say a 10GB file into notepad, or anything else. std::string is going to be about the smallest way to store the data, as its all contiguous memory. It's probably not the best though as insertions will be expensive in time. crashmstr's ides of using a std::vector<std::string> isn't a bad jumping off point though. If you do more complex things you'll need to eventuate what the best structure is to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "editor of sorts" is probably the important thing: if the text were read-only, you could consider using `mmap`. I don't have enough experience with memory mapped files to know if they're appropriate for text editors, however.

There are data structures more suited to modifying large chunks of text. A [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) is a binary tree with short text strings at the leaf nodes... operations on a string such as appending some text might cause the leaf node to be split and the appended text added into the righthand new node. This has the advantage that existing strings don't always need to be repeated moved or grown as the text document is modified.

Another alternative is a simpler structure called a [gap buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer). This effectively uses three strings to hold your text, a prefix, a postfix and a pre-sized gap. When the user starts work on a section of text, the document is split into the prefix and postfix strings, and a new gap buffer is allocated. The text the user adds is pushed into the gap buffer which may be expanded as needed. When they move on to a different point in the document, the gap buffer is merged with the other strings and a new gap is created. The assumption here is that most of the document will be static, with most edits occurring around a specific location in the document at any given time, minimising string copies, moves and reallocations.

Emacs uses gap buffers, which suggests they're not a bad place to start. There's plenty of discussion (and comparison) of the two datastructures out there, and you may even be able to find perfectly useable implementations already available. Implementing your own gap buffer should be dead easy.

Possibly useful reading: [Gap Buffers, or, Don’t Get Tied Up With Ropes?](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2009/02/18/gap-buffers-or-why-bother-with-1/) (which includes some profiling information), [original SGI C++ library Rope docs](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html)

Comment: Thank you.  Great answer to an admittedly vague question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for a vague question, my answer is that probably std::string will suite you well. 
But.. there many ways to store this, it depends on how are you development requisites.

Edit: Complementary Answer (edited question) No, it's not inefficient at all. It's quite suitable for generic use and excelent for readlonly access.

Comment: I like this answer. The STL is made for the general case, we have a general case, so use the STL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vague question that is why you can't find a good answer. It is more about what you do with this text file. If the text file is small enough to be stored in memory then sure you can store it in a string. But then how are you going to use it? What does this do for you?
Are you going to use regex for find certain words? Then sure you can do that but it may be slow.

Is the the text file a webpage(source)? Then sure you can do that and search for the tags you are looking for. There might be better ways like putting it into an xml tree and searching for the tags but the ONE string should still work.

Anyway this is a tough question to answer because we don't know what you are using the string for in the first place.

If you just need it whole and intact then if you have enough memory to store it in a string then sure.